# Youtube Insert Subsciption API Possible Fail

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are developing an application, and through this application, people can connect their social media accounts and perform some operations with a single click.

In our experiments, our members subscribe to the channel with one click, but we cannot see this in Youtube Statistics, on the contrary, the number of subscribers decreases.

Is it because it perceives us as bots? Or is there another reason?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: `Is it because it perceives us as bots?` - probably. Only them (*YouTube*) know the reason. Also, you didn't show any code. Are you sure your code does indeed complete the subscription successfully?

Comment: Yeah I am pretty sure the code is working great. I can see the channel in my subscription list. So, should I wait to see any changes appear at subscriber count in my channel?